# opening maven project in Linux built in windows

Tags: linux, windows, maven, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-neon

I tried to open a maven project in Linux that I build in windows. It shows this error

ERROR:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'dota'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

How to solve it?

Found that it is this:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
but unable to figure out how to proceed!

Comment: No access to maven repositories...Proxy/Firewall in your linux box?

Comment: try creating a new maven project instead!